# Permissions on LibreOffice 6.0 snap

Tags: permissions, libreoffice, snap

I received the latest update of LibreOffice, which seems to be a snap package; the help/about says:

```
Version: 6.0.1.1
Build ID: libreoffice-6.0.1.1-snap1
CPU threads: 4; OS: Linux 4.4; UI render: default; VCL: gtk3; 
Locale: en-US (en_US.UTF-8); Calc: group
```

Unfortunately I can't open any files that are on my mounted drives other than the usual Documents, Music, Pictures, and such. I have several other local partitions under `/mnt`, and have never had problems accessing them with any other application, so I suspect the problem is with how the snap itself is configured.

Having never used a snap, I'm unsure what to do to correct this; do I need to add the snap to some group or another?

Since most of the files I actually use with LibreOffice are not in the generic directories, it isn't all that useful, but it looks quite interesting, so I'm hoping someone can help.

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I'm using 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04 with all the latest updates.

Answer (score 3):

Try connecting the removable-media interface:

```
sudo snap connect libreoffice:removable-media
```

This interface has just been approved for autoconnect, so you shouldn't need to do this in the short future:
https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/request-auto-connection-of-removable-media-for-libreoffice/2660