# Access /opt from Libreoffice

Tags: permissions, libreoffice, snap, zotero

On my Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS System I changed from the preinstalled Libreoffice to Libreoffice from Snap (libreoffice-6.4.1.2-snap1). Trying to reinstall the Zotero Extension I realised, that accessing `/opt` is not possible, showing this error:

```
(soffice:14679): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 11:14:38.709: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Permission denied (g-file-error-quark, 2)
```

In Software I set the permissions to connections on removable media (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1005936/permissions-on-libreoffice-6-0-snap)), running as sudo is somehow not possible, changing owner of /opt doesn't help. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Snap packages, by default, only have access to a user's home folders, for security reasons. You could try a symlink:

`sudo ln -s /opt /home/$USER/opt`

Which will create a symbolic link of `/opt` into your home folder.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it still denieds permission. I even tried to directly symlink the extension - but no success. I guess the only option is to install the Extension in a user-owned folder?!

Answer (score 0):

I un- and reinstalled the Zotero Plugin completely via Softwarestore and it automatically installed the plugin into Writer.